# How to add a seconds to a timestamp value which is in your another variable/dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

```py
lv_seconds_back = mv_time_horizon.select(col("max(time_horizon)") * 60).show() 
mv_now          =spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as mv_now")
local_date_time  =mv_now.select(date_format('mv_now', 'HH:mm:ss').alias("local_date_time"))
lv_start         =local_date_time.select(col("local_date_time") - expr("INTERVAL $lv_seconds_back seconds"))
```

How do i substract no of seconds which is in `lv_seconds_back` variable in the `lv start`

I tried using `expr(interval seconds)` but it wont take the variable but takes number.

Also if I need too add that `lv_start` in the query how do i do that

```py
mt_cache_fauf_r_2= spark.sql("select mt_cache_fauf_r_temp from mt_cache_fauf_r_temp where RM_ZEITPUNKT>= ${lv_start} & RM_ZEITPUNKT <=  ${lv_end}")
```

This doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove `.show()` so that your column is captured in `lv_seconds_back` variable.

Comment: yes, its already captured in lv_seconds_back but how do i assign this later

Answer (score 0):

Your first line has two issues. The first one: `col("max(time_horizon)")` cannot work because the `col` function expects a column name. Either do `expr("max(time_horizon)")` or `max(col("time_horizon"))`. Then, the `show` function displays part of the dataframe but does not return anything. Therefore it does not make sense to assign the result of `show` to a variable.

If you remove `show` and with the `col` call, the result is a dataframe with one row of one element. The `first` function can get you the `Row` object from which you can access its only element like this:

```py
lv_seconds_back = mv_time_horizon.select(F.expr("max(time_horizon)") * 60).first()[0]
```

Then, if you want to substract that value from a timestamp, do it before you convert it to a string:

```py
mv_now  = spark.sql(f"select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - {lv_seconds_back}) as mv_now")
```